# loop a sound at set intervals

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm relativly new to this so please bear with me.
I need to know how to loop a sound (or any object for that matter) at a definable interval.
Something simple like, touch a button and a small sound file plays every x seconds until you touch another button or touch the same button again.

Answer (score 5):

[NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) is what you're looking for to perform an action at specific time intervals.

Creating a simple timer to perform some action every 5 seconds would look something like this:

```
//This will start a repeating timer that will fire every 5 seconds
-(IBAction)startTimer {
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(someAction:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
}

//The method the timer will call when fired
-(void)someAction:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    //Do stuff here
}


-(IBAction)stopTimer {
    [self.timer invalidate];
}
```

As far as playing sounds go, iOS provides a lot of options.  Fortunately Apple has provided plenty of [good documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6) on the different options available to you, how to choose the right one, and implement it.

Comment: Also checkout performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:  which can be simpler to code